# Using oauth2 in an iframe application

Tags: google-oauth

I have a web application that uses google & facebook oauth2 to authorize the users.
But, the application can also be hosted in other sites in a frame.

The problem is that in that case google blocks the login phase (since it's in a frame), is there a way to overcome it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. If possible stay away from embedding other site with frames.

Answer (score 0):

You could contrive something where your client makes an ajax call to your server. If your server send the login redirect, your client can use the 302 location to open a popup window. You will of course need to make sure the user isn't blocking popups.